# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with WAMP and an htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

i have a problem with an .htacess from a website i bought. i use Wampserver to try to edit the css design .
i have created a virtualhost ** artwebsite.local ** , the rewrite_module is on .
but when i load the website i have this :

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

info : when i remove the website's files and try with simple php file  ( hello word ) it's working ( without an htaccess.
thank you for your help

the httacess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#301 > HTTS with www

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.domain.fr/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

#301 > HTTS without www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://artwebsite.local/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

### Rewriting / request uri to router.php ###

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*?)$ router.php [QSA,L]

### Rewriting index and general urls ###

RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)/index.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)/$ router.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)$ /$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)/index.htm$ router.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)/([.-_/a-z0-9]*).php$ router.php?lang=$1 [QSA]

### Rewriting ulrs ads, shops and page by language ###

RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+-([0-9]+)$ router.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+$ router.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+$ router.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+$ router.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+$ router.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|it|ru|ar)/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+$ router.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

### Rewriting ulrs ads, shops and page whithout language ###

RewriteRule ^[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+-([0-9]+)$ router.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+$ router.php [L]
RewriteRule ^[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+$ router.php [L]
RewriteRule ^[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+$ router.php [L]
RewriteRule ^[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+$ router.php [L]
RewriteRule ^[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+/[ء-يa-zA-ZA-Яа-я0-9-]+$ router.php [L]

### Rewriting all urls containing a php script name ###

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^artwebsite\.local
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)+\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(invoices/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*?)$ router.php [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://artwebsite.local/404
```

i try to change the .htacess , the configuration of wanpserver is ok .

the virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName artwebsite.local
    DocumentRoot "d:/artweb"
    <Directory  "d:/artweb/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That htaccess looks like it is forcing users to use HTTPS Did you create a certificate and all the things you have to do to run with SSL/TLS?

Comment: thanks for your answer RiggsFolly , yes i tried with openSSL , a key and a certificate .

Comment: So, to confirm, you can access your “simple php file” using the HTTPS URL `https://artwebsite.local/helloworld.php`? The server config you’ve posted would not allow this. (?)

Comment: So did you define your https virtual host in `wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.57\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf` If so show us that also

Comment: Yes i can access with a simple php file to https://artwebsite.local/helloworld.php

Comment: `<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
ServerName artwebsite.local:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/key/certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/key/private.key"

</VirtualHost>`